# php custom mvc framework | Load a view file as a string

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-get-contents

I want to implement functionality like CodeIgniter does in its loadview function - 
While loading the view we pass third parameter "true" so that the page will be taken as a string.

Using `file_get_contents()` is correct option while wrting custom mvc framework ?

I hav a function to load view as -

```
function loadView($directoryPath, $page, $data = array()) {

        extract($data);
        // construct path for loading the view
        $viewURL = $GLOBALS['config']['dir-views'];
        $path = $viewURL . DS . $directoryPath . DS . $page;

        // actual loading of a view.  
        include $path;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your goals. If you want to get the raw view data then use `file_get_contents()`. If a view contains any php code that needs to be executed use [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Ob_start example:

```
function loadView($directoryPath, $page, $data = array()) {

    extract($data);
    // construct path for loading the view
    $viewURL = $GLOBALS['config']['dir-views'];
    $path = $viewURL . DS . $directoryPath . DS . $page;

    // actual loading of a view.  
    ob_start(); // Turn on output buffering
    include $path; // Output the result to the buffer
    return ob_get_clean(); // Get current buffer contents and delete current output buffer
}
```

[ob_end_clean()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

Comment: I want to make AJAX call which will bring some info and then that info will be shown in popup. So contents in the popup are written in a file. So which way will be better ?.
thank you for the option `ob_start` will look into it also.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind is to create the renderView($filePath, $params) function with ob_start and include functional, then use it like renderView('myview.html.php', $someInfo). $someInfo variable will be available in the template

Comment: Question updated.
I have a function loadview as shown above.
here, is there any need of using ob_start function ? I am not clear.

Comment: Actually, there is no need to use this function. Without it the loadView function will output the result. If you want this function to return string result use ob_start.